# Image Array in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I am working on a project based on Template Matching using OpenCV.

How  can I make an array of images ?

```
cv::Mat ref_temp[7]; // Array Declaration as we do in c/c++
cv::Mat image = cv::imread("ref.jpg",1);  
cv::Mat ref_image;

image.copyTo( ref_image);   

cv::Mat ref_temp(1) =(ref_image, cv::Rect(550,85, 433, 455));
cv::Mat ref_temp[2] =(ref_image, cv::Rect(1042,85,433, 455));
cv::Mat ref_temp[3] =(ref_image, cv::Rect(1528,85,433, 455));
cv::Mat ref_temp[4] =(ref_image, cv::Rect(65, 1010, 423, 442));
cv::Mat ref_temp[5] =(ref_image, cv::Rect(548, 1010, 423, 442));
cv::Mat ref_temp[6] =(ref_image, cv::Rect(1025, 1010, 423, 442));
cv::Mat ref_temp[7] =(ref_image, cv::Rect(1529, 1010, 423, 442));
```

I am not sure I am doing it in a right way.
Please help me.

Comment: Can you tell us more about what you want to accomplish? Are you getting compiler or runtime errors? If so, what do those errors say? I'm not familiar with Template Matching. Do you want to create an array of images that are scaled to different sizes:?

Comment: Actually, I am using one reference image named as ref_image and then I am taking the reference templates from that image (as per the co-ordinates). Now I have 8 different images cut from the reference image. I want to store these images in a array.

Comment: @ahoffer : I am not familiar with the opencv coding methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a region of interest (ROI) from `ref_image`, where the top-left corner of the ROI is (550, 85), and the width and height is 443 & 455:

```
cv::Mat ref_img_roi(ref_image, cv::Rect(550, 85, 433, 455);
```

Next, assign the the ROI to your image array:

```
ref_temp[0] = ref_img_roi;
```

Now, the `ref_temp[0]` references to the region specified in `ref_img_roi` of the`ref_image`.

In your code, the usage of the C++ array is incorrect. You don't have to put `cv::Mat` when using the `ref_temp`. And, the index of array should be 0 ~ 6.
The following code will work:

```
cv::Mat ref_temp[7];
cv::Mat image = cv::imread("ref.jpg",1);  
cv::Mat ref_image;
image.copyTo( ref_image);

ref_temp[0] = cv::Mat(ref_image, cv::Rect(550, 85, 433, 455));
ref_temp[1] = cv::Mat(ref_image, cv::Rect(1042, 85, 433, 455));
ref_temp[2] = cv::Mat(ref_image, cv::Rect(1528, 85, 433, 455));
ref_temp[3] = cv::Mat(ref_image, cv::Rect(65, 1010, 423, 442));
ref_temp[4] = cv::Mat(ref_image, cv::Rect(548, 1010, 423, 442));
ref_temp[5] = cv::Mat(ref_image, cv::Rect(1025, 1010, 423, 442));
ref_temp[6] = cv::Mat(ref_image, cv::Rect(1529, 1010, 423, 442));
```

Comment: user3207049 - if you did reall appreciated it, you would have upvoted the answer of @mcchu